# Let fontsize inside command proportionally resize

Tags: fonts

I would like to write a `\newcommand` to define a stylish word, like `\LaTeX`.

Let's take this example:

```
\newcommand{\mystyle}{
     \textit{\raisebox{+0.2ex}{M}
     \kern-0.66em\raise-0.3ex\hbox{\scriptsize y}
     \kern-0.3em\raise0.4ex\hbox{\scriptsize s}
     \kern-0.75em\raise-0.3ex\hbox{\scriptsize t}
     \kern-0.3em\hbox{yle}
     }
     }
```

The problem is, when `\mystyle` is put inside `\title{}` or `\section{}` the fontsizes which are defined by brute force (1st 4 letters) get too small since they do not proportionally scale with the remaining letters. If I write `\LaTeX` inside `\title{}` there is no problem.

How to get my command working smoothly like that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `relsize` package for this.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{relsize}

\newcommand{\mystyle}{
     \textit{\raisebox{+0.2ex}{M}
     \kern-0.66em\raise-0.3ex\hbox{\relsize{-1}y}
     \kern-0.3em\raise0.4ex\hbox{\relsize{-1}s}
     \kern-0.75em\raise-0.3ex\hbox{\relsize{-1}t}
     \kern-0.3em\hbox{yle}
     }
     }

\begin{document}

\section{\mystyle}

Text talking about \mystyle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem cannot really be solved with `relsize`.

You can use the fact that `\check@mathfonts` sets up the font sizes for subscripts and superscripts based on the current font size, saving it in `\sf@size`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mystyle}{%
  \textit{%
    \check@mathfonts
    \itshape
    \raisebox{0.2ex}{M}%
    \kern-0.1em
    \raisebox{-0.3ex}{\fontsize\sf@size\z@\selectfont y}%
    \kern-0.1em
    \raisebox{0.4ex}{\fontsize\sf@size\z@\selectfont s}%
    \kern-0.2em
    \raisebox{-0.3ex}{\fontsize\sf@size\z@\selectfont t}%
    yle%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mystyle

\bigskip

\Large\mystyle

\bigskip

\footnotesize\mystyle

\end{document}
```

Note that you had several spaces (due to unprotected end-of-lines) that I removed, so the kerning had to be changed. Fix it to your liking.

[image]

Comment: What are the down sides to using `relsize`? I was going to suggest `\scalebox`, but I like your `\check@mathfonts` much better.

Comment: Neat :). Are there other font sizes saved by `\check@mathfonts`?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik `\ssf@size` has the size for second level subscripts/superscripts.